# Counting specific rows in a sequence depending on function

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, reshape

Let's say I have a data frame consisting of a number of rows sequenced, like this:

```
mag_numbers <- c(rep(seq(1,-1,length.out = 601),times=3), 
                 rep(seq(1,0.98,length.out = 601),times=2))
time <- c(rep(seq(90,54144,length.out = 601),times=2), 
          rep(seq(90,49850,length.out = 601),times=3))
data = data.frame(time=rep(time,times=6), mag=rep(mag_numbers, times=6))
data

  time       mag
1  90.00 1.0000000
2 180.09 0.9966667
3 270.18 0.9933333
4 360.27 0.9900000
5 450.36 0.9866667
6 540.45 0.9833333
*
*
*
*
18025 49435.33 0.9801667
18026 49518.27 0.9801333
18027 49601.20 0.9801000
18028 49684.13 0.9800667
18029 49767.07 0.9800333
18030 49850.00 0.9800000
```

Inside the data I would like to summarize some parameter depending on some condition. Those conditions are:

1) count the time column rows for those are in the range of from 90 to 54000 if some of them not in this range skip them. Note: Assume that one data_set if the time value in between 90 and 54000 values.

2) Inside of all data_sets, count how many of mag columns showed >0 or <0 values. Note: One value is enough for indicating that data_set is switched

3)summarize switched states inside of all states like this

```
ss(switched state)/total(all data_sets)
```

4) for the data sets which satisfies the range 90:54000, check the mag for the first observation of the number <0 together with corresponding time. Note: In each data set (switched state data sets) there is only one time value and one mag value for this.

outputs should like this

1) data_sets

> 12

2) data_set[mag] < 0

> 9

3) ss/total

> 9/12

4)

```
               time          mag
data_set1  27207.09 -0.003333333
data_set2  27297.18 -0.006666667
data_set3  27387.27 -0.010000000
data_set4  27477.36 -0.013333333
```

So the main problem is how can I perform these actions in a function? and all the data in a directory after reading them.

Comment: Does anyone has the answer?

Comment: Your question appears to be a bit unclear. What is a data set? Do you mean a subset of your original data.frame? In 1) it would appear you just want to count the number of rows between 90 and 54000, does that sound right?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik a data set means when you `print(data)` number of small chunks that satisfies number of rows between 90 and 54000. yes it should be a subset of original data.frame.

So in 1) I want to count those subsets.

Comment: Please revise your question and be very specific what you mean. For instance, how do you determine chunk size?

Comment: When you write "outputs should like this 1) data_sets  12". This output doesn't correspond to the sample data set you gave does it? To answser point 1) using your example dataset, you could write `data %>% mutate(range = time >90 & time <54000) %>% group_by(range) %>% summarise(n())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
```

#### Plots

Helps viewing what you mean by datasets :

```
plot(data$mag,type="l")
plot(data$time, type = "l")
lapply(list(seq(1,30)),function(i) text(-600+601*i,0,i))
```

#### Give a number to the data sets

```
data$lag <- data$time - lag(data$time) <0
data$lag[is.na(data$lag)] <- 0
data$set <- cumsum(data$lag)
```

For information

```
length(unique(data$set))
# 30
```

#### Reply to point 1)

Find out which datasets are excluded and included

```
excluded <- unique(filter(data, time > 50000)$set)
length(excluded)
# 12
included <- unique(filter(data, ! set %in% excluded)$set)
length(included)
# 18
```

#### Reply to point 2)

If I understand well, you are looking for 
sets which contain both positive and negative mag values
these will have abs(sum(mag) != sum(abs(mag))

```
 switched <- data %>% 
  group_by(set) %>%
  summarise(abs(sum(mag)),
            sum(abs(mag)),
            changedsign = abs(sum(mag))!=sum(abs(mag)))
length(unique(filter(switched, changedsign)$set))
# 18
length(unique(filter(switched, changedsign &
                      set %in% included)$set))
# 6
```

#### Reply to point 3)

```
cat(length(unique(filter(switched, changedsign &
                      set %in% included)$set)), 
    "/",
    length(unique(filter(data, ! set %in% excluded)$set)))
```

I don't clearly understand point 4.

#### One plot for each dataset

If you have the ggplot2 package installed:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = time, y = mag, 
               color = set %in% included)) +
geom_line() + 
facet_wrap(~set)
```

[image: One plot for each dataset showing which are included or not]

Comment: Please see the data with utils::View(Data)
you will see time column sometimes in different range (90:54000, and 90:49850)
for reply point 1) I don't need all rows. just count those ones 90 and 54000 so that means 601 rows is a one data set. If the rows in between 90 and 49850 dont count them as data set. 
I think you can imagine now the answer of point 2 and rest then.

Comment: "just count those ones 90 and 54000" do you mean only those which are equal to 90 and equal to 54000 ` nrow(filter(data, time %in% c(90,540000))) ` there are only 30 of these. I don't understand your definition of the range. Show me the command that gives you 601 as a result.

Comment: Ah ok now I see plot(data$time, type="l") you mean rows number 1 to 601 represent one dataset. And this dataset is counted in the range because it has 2 time points> 54000.

Comment: I have edited my answer to give a number to each dataset and show which are excluded and which ones are included. It seems I still get different answers to what you expect for "ss(switched state)/total(all data_sets)".

Comment: dear @Paul4forest thank you very much for your code. It works great. but its better to say first install `dplyr` package:) by the way for **Reply to point 3)** differen asnwer is ok. It was a just assumption. I didnt know the real output "ss(switched state)/total(all data_sets)". So can we also give the output also as a numerical value automatically after showing 8 / 16 value? which is 0.33333

Comment: for **Reply to point 4) ** What I mean was; extracting time values of first observation of negative mag values inside of each those switched states.

so there should be 6 time values and 6 mag values each. I try to find out disturbution of time deviation in each dataset.

Comment: dear  @Paul4forest can you add comments side of your codes what they are doing particularly. It will be easy for us to follow. In addition, how can we apply these commands inside of a function and use this function for all different data, for ex. data, data1,data2.... etc ?

Comment: I'm glad you like the answer. Of course just divide the 2 values: ̀length(unique(filter(switched, changedsign & set %in% included)$set))/length(unique(filter(data, ! set %in% excluded)$set))`

Comment: @Thabescity to understand what a functions does, enter ?function_name at the R command prompt. To place this in a function, create a myfunction <- function(data){ all operations and output} see function definition in the R help.